# I need to make a JFrame or a JDialog that even if you change window it stays focused so that the keylistener will listen

Tags: java, swing, jframe, keylistener, jdialog

I need to have a frame or dialog that stays focused even if I change window.
I am building an AutoClicker and it needs while it's clicking in another window to listen to my keyListener so that the user will be able to start/stop it.

```
    d.setModalityType(ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);// d is my JDialog
    d.addKeyListener(this);
    d.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    d.toFront();
    d.requestFocus();

    d.setFocusableWindowState(true);

    d.setFocusable(true);
```

Comment: There's real way to do that, besides, it's counterintuitive. If your window has focus, then typing can't be registered by the other window (which needs the event).  Instead, you will need to investigate the use of a global event monitor through the use of JNI/JNA to hook into the OS's native event queue

Comment: Thanks I'll try and understand the JNI.